# Зачем нужна папка "\\\\.\\ "?

Tags: windows

Что хранится по этому пути? Знаю только, что там есть файл `PhysicalDrive0`, в котором хранятся данные о запуске системы.

Comment: вроде бы, насколько я в курсе, это как раз и есть "точка монтирования корневой файловой системы": в *ms/windows* она "глубоко спрятана", вероятно, чтобы не шокировать *простого пользователя (tm)*, в [posix-совместимых операционных системах она (`/`) "лежит на поверхности"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#Conventional_directory_layout)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Никакой папки `\\\\.\\`  не существует. Существует префикс `\\.\` (при записи в строковых константах в Си-подобных языках обратная косая черта удваивается), который используется для передачи в функцию *CreateFile* имени устройства вместо имени файла. Например `\\.\PhysicalDrive0` соответствует диску, `\\.\COM1` - последовательному порту и т.п.

Подробнее см. в [Win32 Device Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#win32-device-namespaces)

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял твой вопрос, ты имеешь в виду `\\.\ (\\?\)`. Не уверен точно, как это объяснить. 
Этот префикс самые прошаренные используют для создания и удаления запрещенных папок) Пример:

```
md \\?\C:\Users\User\con\
echo Создает папку con, которую по идее нельзя создать в windows
rd \\?\C:\Users\User\con
echo Удаляет её же
md \\?\D:\lpt1
rd \\?\D:\lpt1
```

Точно такие же махинации можно проворачивать, используя `.` вместо `?`:

```
md \\.\C:\con
rd \\.\C:\con
```

Что интересно, так это то, что в эту папку из консоли не перейти.

```
echo Я создал две папки - con и aux (обе нельзя создать по идее)
cd con
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
cd aux
Системе не удается найти указанный путь.
```

Так же нельзя использовать `\\.\ (\\?\)` для перехода:

```
cd \\?\C:\con
"\\?\C:\con"
CMD.exe не поддерживает пути UNC в качестве текущей папки.
echo То же самое с точкой.
cd \\.\C:\con
"\\.\C:\con"
CMD.exe не поддерживает пути UNC в качестве текущей папки.
```

## Что говорит Google по поводу UNC:

## Universal Naming Convention (условная конвенция наименований)

Стандарт для идентификации **серверов**, принтеров и других ресурсов **в сети**, которые зародились в комьюнити Unix. UNC-путь использует двойные косые черты или обратные косые черты, чтобы предшествовать имени компьютера.

## Насколько я понял сам, UNC `(\\?\)` является сетевым путем.

Comment: Если это не то, что было нужно, то я удалю ответ

Comment: \\?\ это не совсем UNC, это префикс, который отключает проверки WinAPI, в первую очередь по длине пути. То, что он позволяет создать файл с запрещенным именем не знал, интересно. И с префиксом \\.\ для Device Namespace он похоже взаимозаменяем. А CMD.exe просто все, что начинается с \\ отпихивает как UNC.