# Что это за путь «\\\\.\\»?

Tags: c++

Часто встречал в коде начало пути по типу: `\\\\.\\Что то там`. Что это за пути такие?

Comment: Вы бы хоть как-то заголовок изменили, чтобы понятно было. Это майкрософтовская *Universal Naming Convention* см. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file. Например `\\.\COM45` порт последовательный

Comment: Как мне изменить заголовок или сделать уточнение когда я не знаю что это?)

Comment: ну хотя бы добавить в заголовок \\\\.\\ может кому тоже интересно...

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем нужна папка "\\\\.\\ "?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/811791/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Это майкрософтовская Universal Naming Convention. Например `\\.\COM45` порт последовательный.

docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file.

Comment: Ну и чего ссылку посеял?